# In CKEditor getSelection() returns null value in IE

Tags: ckeditor, selection

I am having an small code to select an text in CKEditor. For that i am using following code in javascript.

```
        var docx = editor.document;
        var elementx = docx.getById(id);
        editor.getSelection().selectElement(elementx);
        editor.getSelection().scrollIntoView(true);
```

It works fine in Mozilla Firefox.But in IE9 it throws an error as selectElement is not an object. So i checked the code and found that getSelection() having an null value. Please help me how to solve it.
I tried some answers given in various sites even in CKEditor fourms nothing helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the correct solution:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
editor.focus(); // Without this selection will be null on IE.

var element = editor.document.getBody().getLast(),
    selection = editor.getSelection();

selection.selectElement(element); // You have to reuse selection.
selection.scrollIntoView();
```

I tested this from the console on Firefox, Chrome and IE8 on http://ckeditor.com/demo and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for ur rply.. that 'slection' variable having null only. that getSelection() function still return null only..

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Just i am try to select the particular tag based on the id. when i select it should be highlighted and scroll into that position this what i want.

Comment: Ok, but that's what I did and my code works for me. Could you e.g. create example on jsfiddle in which ```getSelection()``` returns null? And specify on which browser it happens.

Comment: It's happens only in IE. IE version 9 only i checked.

Comment: Thank you Reinmar! I was having about the same problem and editor.focus() fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
var docx = editor.document;
var elementx = docx.getById(id);

var resRange = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );
resRange.selectNodeContents( elementx );
resRange.collapse();
editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ resRange ] );
resRange.endContainer.$.scrollIntoView();
```

---

This may have something to do with what IE9 considers to be an object. Have you tried selecting different element types?

Maybe grabbing the parent of the element will give you something that IE9 considers to be an object, you can try this:

```
var docx = editor.document;
var elementx = docx.getById(id);
var parentx = elementx.getParent();
parentx.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for u to spending time to read my all questions. I dont know why i am always getting error for all code.. U'r code also gives an that selectRanges() is not an  object error.

Comment: See if the addition to my answer helps.